# Adding additional information to Simple Jquery FileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to integrate juqery fileupload with an ajax form submit. The ajax form sends the text and returns the ID of the newly created event, This is necessary to know which event to link with when uploading.
The simple upload demo uses the following code

Here's the ajax that first upload the non-file fields

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: '/whats-on/upload-event/',
       data: JSON.stringify(data),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       traditional: true,
       success: function (return_data) {
           console.log(return_data)
       }
    });
```

It returns the following json

```
Object {status: true, id: 17162}
```

However the fileupload sends the files without declaring `data: data,`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="fileupload" type="file" data-url="server/php/">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                //Returns ID as e['id'] and 200 status also with e['status']
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: call another ajax inside `done` function.

Comment: Pass the non-file data as query string, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get the event Id with an ajax post:

```
function uploadClick(){
   var eventId = getEvent();
   uploadFile(eventId)
}

function getEvent(){
   // make an ajax and return your id
}
```

One you got it, then create an URL with a query string indicating the eventId. this URL is where you want to post your file:

```
function uploadFile(eventId){
    // attatch the id to the URL with query string
    url = url + '&eventId=' + eventId;

    // submit here your file
}
```

This way you can post in the same ajax call the file itself and the event id. In you server side action you need to get this query string and then pick the posted file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to handle callbacks for fileupload plugin like:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    url: <url>,
                    type: <HTTP_VERB>,
                    other configurations...

                }).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                    //fires when you select a file to upload
                }).bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
                    //fires when upload completed successfully. equivalent to done call back of jQuery ajax
                }).bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
                  //fires when upload fails
                });
```

For complete reference please take a look at the following [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) .